# iOS 15 Safari search bar color

Tags: css, ios, safari, mobile-safari

As shown [here](https://css-tricks.com/safari-15-new-ui-theme-colors-and-a-css-tricks-cameo/) it's possible to change the color of the top bar below the notch.

By using

```
<meta name="theme-color" 
      content="#ecd96f" 
      media="(prefers-color-scheme: light)">
<meta name="theme-color" 
      content="#0b3e05" 
      media="(prefers-color-scheme: dark)">
```

But how do I change the color of the bottom search/ tab bar?
It's not done with the snippet I posted.

Is there any other new meta tag I can use for this?
[image: Example image]

Answer (score 1):

From my testing, the bottom bar inherits the background color of the body element. The top bar is also set to the same color when `"theme-color"` meta tag is not set.

```css
  body {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
```